# Using preg_match to retrieve data from html source

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Please take a look at below source code

```
LMS.pageData['product']['thumbnails'].push({
                            zoomUrl: 'http://07fcfb85ff11d7f5d0fc-f4c51c056b0940e95f0098eed18ef033.r99.cf3.rackcdn.com/4403569-SPLSPR15MJKT-SPORT-A2-SSP15_01-800.jpg',
                            url: 'http://07fcfb85ff11d7f5d0fc-f4c51c056b0940e95f0098eed18ef033.r99.cf3.rackcdn.com/4403569-SPLSPR15MJKT-SPORT-A2-SSP15_01-480.jpg',
                            smallUrl: 'http://07fcfb85ff11d7f5d0fc-f4c51c056b0940e95f0098eed18ef033.r99.cf3.rackcdn.com/4403569-SPLSPR15MJKT-SPORT-A2-SSP15_01-110.jpg'
                        });

                        LMS.pageData['product']['thumbnails'].push({
                            zoomUrl: 'http://07fcfb85ff11d7f5d0fc-f4c51c056b0940e95f0098eed18ef033.r99.cf3.rackcdn.com/4403569-SPLSPR15MJKT-SPORT-A2-SSP15_02-800.jpg',
                            url: 'http://07fcfb85ff11d7f5d0fc-f4c51c056b0940e95f0098eed18ef033.r99.cf3.rackcdn.com/4403569-SPLSPR15MJKT-SPORT-A2-SSP15_02-480.jpg',
                            smallUrl: 'http://07fcfb85ff11d7f5d0fc-f4c51c056b0940e95f0098eed18ef033.r99.cf3.rackcdn.com/4403569-SPLSPR15MJKT-SPORT-A2-SSP15_02-110.jpg'
                        });

                        LMS.pageData['product']['thumbnails'].push({
                            zoomUrl: 'http://07fcfb85ff11d7f5d0fc-f4c51c056b0940e95f0098eed18ef033.r99.cf3.rackcdn.com/4403569-SPLSPR15MJKT-SPORT-A2-SSP15_03-800.jpg',
                            url: 'http://07fcfb85ff11d7f5d0fc-f4c51c056b0940e95f0098eed18ef033.r99.cf3.rackcdn.com/4403569-SPLSPR15MJKT-SPORT-A2-SSP15_03-480.jpg',
                            smallUrl: 'http://07fcfb85ff11d7f5d0fc-f4c51c056b0940e95f0098eed18ef033.r99.cf3.rackcdn.com/4403569-SPLSPR15MJKT-SPORT-A2-SSP15_03-110.jpg'
                        });

                        LMS.pageData['product']['thumbnails'].push({
                            zoomUrl: 'http://07fcfb85ff11d7f5d0fc-f4c51c056b0940e95f0098eed18ef033.r99.cf3.rackcdn.com/4403569-SPLSPR15MJKT-SPORT-A2-SSP15_04-800.jpg',
                            url: 'http://07fcfb85ff11d7f5d0fc-f4c51c056b0940e95f0098eed18ef033.r99.cf3.rackcdn.com/4403569-SPLSPR15MJKT-SPORT-A2-SSP15_04-480.jpg',
                            smallUrl: 'http://07fcfb85ff11d7f5d0fc-f4c51c056b0940e95f0098eed18ef033.r99.cf3.rackcdn.com/4403569-SPLSPR15MJKT-SPORT-A2-SSP15_04-110.jpg'
                        });

                        LMS.pageData['product']['thumbnails'].push({
                            zoomUrl: 'http://07fcfb85ff11d7f5d0fc-f4c51c056b0940e95f0098eed18ef033.r99.cf3.rackcdn.com/4403569-SPLSPR15MJKT-SPORT-A2-SSP15_05-800.jpg',
                            url: 'http://07fcfb85ff11d7f5d0fc-f4c51c056b0940e95f0098eed18ef033.r99.cf3.rackcdn.com/4403569-SPLSPR15MJKT-SPORT-A2-SSP15_05-480.jpg',
                            smallUrl: 'http://07fcfb85ff11d7f5d0fc-f4c51c056b0940e95f0098eed18ef033.r99.cf3.rackcdn.com/4403569-SPLSPR15MJKT-SPORT-A2-SSP15_05-110.jpg'
                        });
```

I need to retrieve values for zoomUrl , as you can see in above sample code we have 5 zoomUrl.

thanks!

Comment: since you push all the value to an array so why don't you iterate that array to get all your values?

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
preg_match_all('(zoomUrl: \'(.+?)\')', $html, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

This should create an output like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => zoomUrl: 'http://07fcfb85ff11d7f5d0fc-f4c51c056b0940e95f0098eed18ef033.r99.cf3.rackcdn.com/4403569-SPLSPR15MJKT-SPORT-A2-SSP15_01-800.jpg'
            [1] => zoomUrl: 'http://07fcfb85ff11d7f5d0fc-f4c51c056b0940e95f0098eed18ef033.r99.cf3.rackcdn.com/4403569-SPLSPR15MJKT-SPORT-A2-SSP15_02-800.jpg'
            [2] => zoomUrl: 'http://07fcfb85ff11d7f5d0fc-f4c51c056b0940e95f0098eed18ef033.r99.cf3.rackcdn.com/4403569-SPLSPR15MJKT-SPORT-A2-SSP15_03-800.jpg'
            [3] => zoomUrl: 'http://07fcfb85ff11d7f5d0fc-f4c51c056b0940e95f0098eed18ef033.r99.cf3.rackcdn.com/4403569-SPLSPR15MJKT-SPORT-A2-SSP15_04-800.jpg'
            [4] => zoomUrl: 'http://07fcfb85ff11d7f5d0fc-f4c51c056b0940e95f0098eed18ef033.r99.cf3.rackcdn.com/4403569-SPLSPR15MJKT-SPORT-A2-SSP15_05-800.jpg'
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => http://07fcfb85ff11d7f5d0fc-f4c51c056b0940e95f0098eed18ef033.r99.cf3.rackcdn.com/4403569-SPLSPR15MJKT-SPORT-A2-SSP15_01-800.jpg
            [1] => http://07fcfb85ff11d7f5d0fc-f4c51c056b0940e95f0098eed18ef033.r99.cf3.rackcdn.com/4403569-SPLSPR15MJKT-SPORT-A2-SSP15_02-800.jpg
            [2] => http://07fcfb85ff11d7f5d0fc-f4c51c056b0940e95f0098eed18ef033.r99.cf3.rackcdn.com/4403569-SPLSPR15MJKT-SPORT-A2-SSP15_03-800.jpg
            [3] => http://07fcfb85ff11d7f5d0fc-f4c51c056b0940e95f0098eed18ef033.r99.cf3.rackcdn.com/4403569-SPLSPR15MJKT-SPORT-A2-SSP15_04-800.jpg
            [4] => http://07fcfb85ff11d7f5d0fc-f4c51c056b0940e95f0098eed18ef033.r99.cf3.rackcdn.com/4403569-SPLSPR15MJKT-SPORT-A2-SSP15_05-800.jpg
        )

)
```

Demo: https://eval.in/369655